# npm-update with npm-shrinkwrap.json

Tags: node.js, npm

What does running:

```
npm update
```

do if a npm-shrinkwrap.json file exists? Does it

1. Update the dependencies to match the shrinkwrap.json file
2. Update the dependencies to obey package.json (thereby disregarding the shrinkwrap.json file)
3. Not do anything

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you run

```
npm update
```

It will **update the dependencies to obey package.json** and will not care what is stored in `npm-shrinkwrap.json` even when `node_modules` folder is empty which means update command will install using `package.json` while install command will use `npm-shrinkwrap.json`.

It does not make any sense to obey the shrinkwrap file[ in most cases.]

Reason

- It is supposed to be a snapshot of package at some stable point and this thing makes it perfect for production code.
- There are no `^`,`~`,`latest` etc. in shrinkwrap file.
- And we also know that shrinkwrap file is not supposed to be tampered manually using editor
- So all we can do is go back to some previous state of dependencies using this command and this thing can be achieved using npm install

However when you run

```
npm install
```

It follows shrinkwrap file.

But when you run

```
npm install newPkg --save
```

It will change both `package.json` and `npm-shrinkwrap.json` file as well

But when you run

```
npm update pkg --save
```

It will change only `npm-shrinkwrap.json` file and as I wrote before it will use `package.json` file to update according to semver